# Bash script to read a web page list from a text file

Tags: bash, shell-script, wget

I  want to read webpage list and check if some of them have updated. Is it better to use wget or curl and how should I do that?

Webpage list is in a simple text file. If the contents of a webpage is the same it will not print anything. If contents changed from the last time that the script ran, then it will type(stdout) the webpage address.

Comment: Please don't re-post the same question. I have now reopened this one and closed your first one as a duplicate.

Comment: Βάσω, please [edit] your question and show us a few lines of your file with the webpages so we know what we're dealing with. And do you keep the previous versions of the webpages somewhere? Are they simple html files? More complex pages which are generated on the fly?

Comment: Also, please look at the comments on your [original question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/483412/22222) and [edit] this one to provide the details requested.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/sh

i=1
while IFS= read -r url; do
    file="data-$i.out"

    curl -o "$file.new" "$url"

    if ! cmp -s "$file" "$file.new"
    then
        printf '%s\n' "$url"
    fi

    mv -f "$file.new" "$file"

    i=$(( i + 1 ))
done <url-list.txt
```

This would read the URLs from `url-list.txt`, line by line, and use `curl` to fetch each, saving the output in a file called `data-N.out.new` where `N` is an integer (the URL ordinal number in the file).

If there is no old `data-N.out` file, or if this file differs from `data-N.out.new`, then the URL is printed to standard output.

The fetched data file is then renamed for when you run the script again.

The first time you run the script, all URLs will be outputted as they have never been seen before.

Reordering the URLs, or adding new URLs at the top would make the URLs be flagged as changed as the contents of the corresponding data file has changed. You could fix this by using e.g. the base64-encoded URL as part of the output filename instead of `$i`.

Whether you use `curl` or `wget` or some other Web client is essentially unimportant.

Comment: This question is a duplicate. Vote to open the old one, and put answer there. (And maybe edit question to make it clear.)

Comment: Yes that would work. Note there are some edits of the other question (just grammar, punctuation).